# Python IDE with support for metaprogramming

Tags: ide, python

Until recently I have been used [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for my Python needs. I was quite satisfied with its capacities, especially when it came to catching calls to non-existent methods or classes. However I am currently working on a project that requires extensive meta-programming to inject a set of shared methods in a family of classes and Pycharm's Inspector has trouble account of for the classes added this way.

Is there is a Python IDE with a good support for metaprogramming that could solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?